ADF WebActivity results in "Invalid_client" error
I am using ADF's web activity to get the authentication token.
When in Postman, it works correctly for a request looking like this

and with the Headers

Then, I am going to implement this in the Azure Data Factory, and I get the error
Details
{"error_description":"Client authentication failed","error":"invalid_client"}

In the ADF, I first set the variable with the post data.  Note, the "&" are included

and then the actual Web activity performing the POST

Then when I inspect the Input to the web activity it shows what looks correct to me,
the body matches the variable set - so, I don't expect "extra characters"
{
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    "url": "<the URL matches postman>",
    "body": "username=TheUser&password=thePassword@123&client_id=@SSf9ClientIDHereJJL&client_secret=N0ClientPasswordHereub5&grant_type=password&auth_chain=OAuthLdapService"
}

so I do not know what the problem is
